# Phones wifi turns off automatically when im in wifi

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow

When I am using my wifi, after many minutes it disconnects and it will show in my screen that I am connected to my wifi again. What do I do? I checked everything.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well.
Try Disabling power saving apps and see if it works out, if not backup your data and try factory resetting your phone or reflashing it (android) or reinstalling the phone's software via your phone manufacturer'sPC software. If that doesn't solve your problem your phone might have a problem with the antenna.